# R ggplot gives multiple color at the margin of text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making some dot plots with ggplot2 in R. Here is the overall result.

[image: overall]
When zoomed in, I can see multiple colors at the margin of the labels, as well as the dots, which makes it difficult to distinguish different groups.
[image: text]
[image: dot]

Here are part of the code.

```
png(file=paste("dot/",tumorType,"_",cellLine,"_1.png",sep=""), bg="transparent",width = 2048, height = 2048, units = "px",res = 300)

p = ggplot()
p = p + geom_point(data=rocData,aes(x=NES_up,y=NES_down,shape=type,color=CGC),size=3)
p = p + geom_text(data=rocData,aes(x=NES_up+0.005,y=NES_down,label = labels),size = 2,hjust = 0,colour="black")

p = p + scale_shape_manual(values=c(95,124,21))# + scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")
p = p + scale_color_manual(values=c("grey30","red"),labels = c("normal", "CGC"))
p = p + scale_size_manual(values=c(12,8,8))
p = p + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16,face = "bold",vjust=1.5))
p = p + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10),legend.key.size = unit(6,"mm"))
p = p + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour=NA))
p = p + labs(colour="gene type",shape="data group")
p1 = p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(miny,maxy),xlim = c(minx,maxx))
p1 = p1 + labs(y="ES(down)")

p1 = p1 + theme(legend.position="none",axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),plot.margin=unit(c(12,0,0,6),"mm"))
p1= p1 + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=10,hjust=0.5,vjust=0.5))

p2 = p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(miny,maxy),xlim = c(-0.02,0.02))
p2 =p2 + theme(axis.title=element_blank(),axis.text=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),plot.margin=unit(c(12,6,0,0),"mm"))
p2 = p2 + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0))

p3 = p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.02,0.02),xlim = c(minx,maxx))
p3 = p3 + labs(x="ES(up)",y="")  #shape = 19/21
p3 = p3 + theme(legend.position="none",plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,6,6),"mm")) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0),labels=c("0.00"))
p3= p3 + theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=10,hjust=0.5,vjust=0.5))
p3= p3 + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=10,hjust=0.5,vjust=0.5))

p4 = p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.02,0.02),xlim = c(-0.02,0.02))
p4 = p4 + theme(legend.position="none")
p4 = p4 + theme(axis.title=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),axis.text=element_blank(),panel.background=element_blank(),panel.grid=element_blank(),plot.margin=unit(c(0,6,6,0),"mm"))

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, ncol=2, nrow=2,widths=c(4,2), heights=c(4,1),main=textGrob(paste(tumorType,"_",cellLine,sep=""), gp=gpar(fontface="bold",fontsize=16), hjust=0.6,vjust=2.5))

dev.off()
```

The entire plot is composed of four parts with gridExtra package. So my questions is how can I remove the unnecessary margin color in the plot?

Comment: why don't you save it as `pdf`?

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Save as a vector format, e.g. `ps` or `pdf`
2. Increase the resolution, of the `png`, so something like:

   ```
   dpi = 1000
   png("plot.png", width=6*dpi, height=6*dpi, res=dpi)
   ## plotting commands
   dev.off()
   ```

Comment: Yes, vector format is ok, I also take the advice of Mehdi Nellen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is dependent on your OS. `png` takes an argument called `type` which you can try to change to one of these options:

```
type = c("cairo", "Xlib", "quartz")
```

In my case `Xlib` and `quartz` got rid of it. You can check what your default is using `getOption("bitmapType")`

My recommendation is to use vector images:

- `svg`
- `ps`
- `pdf`

You can import them into almost any software (latex, web, libre office)

Comment: It works! My OS is windows, the type has options: `windows`,`cairo` and `cairo-png`. I think the default is `windows`. When I changed it to `cairo`, I found my problem solved. But jagged edges exist, so maybe I should consider vector images. Many thanks!!

Comment: The jacked lines are I think because the anti-aliasing gets turned off probably. But if you're going with vector images this should be no problem.